# Overloaded constructor not getting called in groovy

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I have overloaded a constructor in groovy. But it is not getting called.

Presently I have:

**Default Constructor:**

```
UserServiceClient(){


    String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String((userName + ":" + password ).getBytes()).replaceAll("\n", "")
         headerMap.put("Authorization","Basic " + encoded)

            }
```

**Overloaded Constructor:**

```
UserServiceClient(String baseURI,String userName ,String password) {

               println"inside overloaded constructor"+baseURI

            if(baseURI==null){
                log.error("forms.ldap.baseUri parameter is null,Please configure same in respective property file ")
                throw new NullPointerException()
            }
            if(userName==null)
            {
                log.error("forms.ldap.userName parameter is null,Please configure same in respective property file  ")
                throw new NullPointerException()
            }
            if(password==null)
            {
                log.error("forms.ldap.password parameter is null,Please configure same in respective property file  ")
                throw new NullPointerException()
            }


            String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String((userName + ":" + password ).getBytes()).replaceAll("\n", "")
            println"encoded values :"+encoded
            headerMap.put("Authorization","Basic " + encoded)
            setHeaderMap(headerMap)
      }
```

We are trying to create a object through Spring Bean as:

```
 <bean id="userServiceClient" class="com.user.service.client.UserServiceClient">
    <property name="baseURI" value= "${forms.ldap.baseUri}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${forms.ldap.userName}" />
    <property name="password" value="${forms.ldap.password}" />
    </bean>
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing the 3 properties will create the object with the default constructor, then use setter-based injection for each of the properties (i.e., using `setBaseUri()` method, etc.) on the new object.

Try using constructor injection with `constructor-arg` instead of `property`:

```
<bean id="userServiceClient" class="com.user.service.client.UserServiceClient">
    <constructor-arg value="${forms.ldap.baseUri}" />
    <constructor-arg value="${forms.ldap.userName}" />
    <constructor-arg value="${forms.ldap.password}" />
</bean>
```